# Erro ao conectar executar Query no MySQL + C# - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql

Eu estou tentando fazer uma conexão com a base de dados MySQL através do Visual Studio e já adicionei o banco no gerenciador de Servidores, testei as conexões e deu tudo certo.

O problema esta na parte de executar o código.

> "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados não encontrado e nenhum driver padrão especificado"

Eu pesquisei e vi que tinha que instalar o ODBC driver do MySQL para poder funcionar. Fiz e também não deu certo. Então pesquisei e vi que tinha de adicionar a conexão do ODBC na parte de "Fontes de Dados ODBC" no Painel de Controle / Ferramentas administrativas. Adicionei e também ainda não funcionou.

Acredito que o erro possa estar no código mesmo.

Segue abaixo o que fiz:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace Banco_Dados
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnConectar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.CST;

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                OdbcCommand Cmm = new OdbcCommand();
                Cmm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM cargos";
                Cmm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                Cmm.Connection = con;
                OdbcDataReader rd;
                rd = Cmm.ExecuteReader();            

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(rd);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
                con.Close();                

                MessageBox.Show("Conexão bem sucedida!");
            }
            catch (OdbcException errConn) {// pode ser usado tambem apenas Exception
                MessageBox.Show(errConn.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errConn.Message);
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Onde posso estar errando?

Comment: Utilize o driver correto que é `https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/` instale via nuget e seja feliz

Comment: Procurei mil e uma soluções, e esta foi a unica que conseguiu resolver. Obrigado mesmo!